# mysql - check if former entry of uid has property

Tags: mysql

Since this is my first question here,
pls be gentle :)

In case the following qustion has already been dealt with, 
I would be happy to get some links that answer my qustion.

I have a database which contains a log of items beeing moved around in a warehouse.

example:

tablename: inventory_history

```
Id , Uid , location 
1  |  a1 | location1
2  |  a2 | location2 
3  |  a3 | location3
4  |  a3 | location5
5  |  a2 | badlocation
```

I want to select Id, Uid and location but only if the location of the fromer entry of the same Uid(but lower Id) is not eqaul to 'badlocation'.

So I want to check if the entry of the same Uid with the next lower Id hat 'badlocation' as value for location.

My first thought was to manage this with subquerys but on second thought i think it would be much faster and more clean if one could do this with a join.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.uid, a.location from 
wms_inventory_history as a 
Inner Join wms_inventory_history as b ON (a.uid = b.uid)
Where a.id > b.id limit 1,1 AND
a.location != 'bad_location'
```

Comment: How does `wms_inventory_history` relate to `inventory_history`? And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: After tried that what happen. Please provide the feedback you got.